# How to fall back if elements are missing for a certain index

Tags: python

Is there a way to fall back to an empty value if there are no elements in a certain index of the array

```
foo_val = int(data_arr[3])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: So you want something like a default value?

Comment: What default value do you want to use?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternate to try except:

Its one line instead of 4, and is still readable:

```
foo_val = int(data_arr[3]) if len(data_arr) >= 4 else 0
```

note that `len` is not zero indexed hence >=4 instead of >=3

Comment: nope. we are saying give item at index 3 if data_arr has 4 or more items items in it. If not then fallback to 'fallback value'

Answer (score 1):

Use `try` and `except`.

```
try: # Try doing this piece of code
    foo_val = int(data_arr[3])
except IndexError: # If there is an IndexError, do this piece of code.
    foo_val = 0
```

Comment: no this won't be acceptable, as there would be many such values.

Comment: @Sam How does the amount of such values matter? How does it prevent you from using this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module:

```
dd = collections.defaultdict(int) # default to zero, change as needed
for n, x in enumerate(data_arr):
    dd[n] = x
dd[len(data_arr) + 10] # IndexError for data_arr, returns 0 with defaultdict
```

You can also do this with just a `dict`, by using the `get` method to provide the default value, but a `defaultdict` is a little more convenient.